# How to sign .appxupload files

Tags: uwp, signing, signtool, appx

I have a created a windows phone application using Visual Studio. Using Microsoft `signtool.exe` I can able to sign `.appx` and `.appxbundle` files successfully. Where as while signing `.appxupload` file an error

> The file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.

Command used for signing is:

```
signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /a /f [certificate file] /p [password] "myapp.appxupload"
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: There is no intersection between *"Windows Phone 7"* and *"UWP"*.

Comment: You don't need to sign an `.appxupload` file for app submission. You sign the `appx/appxbundle`, and `.appxupload` is just a compressed file containing the signed binaries (among other files).

Comment: @kennyzx  I have generated app packages myapp.appx,myapp.appxbundle,myapp.appxupload . After generating these three files I have signed myapp.appx,myapp.appxbundle .Will it be sufficient ? or do we need to modify myapp.appxupload?

Comment: Are you sure you are developing an WP7 app? Support for WP7/8/8.1 was discontinued long ago. And you need to sign it from command line?

Comment: Whether it is 8/8.1/10 application package will include .appx/.appxbundle and .appxupload . Can we  sign .appxupload with the help of signtool.exe?

Comment: No. As it clearly stated, `appxupload` is not a supported format for `signtool.exe`. [And I don't think you can sign it with any other tool](https://superuser.com/questions/426337/is-it-possible-to-sign-archives).